# UpdateItem dynamodb condition expression use before or after api execute

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

For dynamodb updates item  condition expression is

**(A)** just WHERE in SQL.

For example, I want to update all items WHERE( condition expression)  price > 10000.

Or

**(B)** the validation to the new data ( after modifying) to success or fail.

For example, the data after update price must be > 10000.

Answer (score 3):

It's most similar to **(A)**, as it's a condition that must be satisfied in order for a conditional update to succeed. If the condition is not met (i.e. it fails), the update will not occur.

This [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html), has some examples of conditions that you can create.